# Update table cannot modify a column which maps to non key preserved tqbles

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, updates

**

```
Update (select l1,l1desc,label,label_desc 
       From member_dig m Join member_label ml 
       On m.member_id =ml.member_id) 
t Set t.l1=t.label, T.l1desc=t.label_desc;
```

**

When I run select alone, result seems fine but my update fails with 'cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table' error.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: From your query it is impossible to understand the columns of which table you want to update. Use the aliases in the list of select's output values to clarify. Make sure that your select does not return more records than you need to update. Also, try using a merge operator that has only branch "when matched then update'.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is very finicky with any `JOIN`s in `UPDATE`s.  On the other hand, it has convenient functionality for updating multiple columns with a single subquery.

So you can do something like this:

```
update member_dig m 
    set (l1, l1desc) = (select ml.label, ml.label_desc
                        from member_label ml
                        where m.member_id = ml.member_id
                       )
    where exists (select 1
                  from member_label ml
                  where m.member_id = ml.member_id
                 );
```

I had to guess on which table is to be updated and where the columns come from, because your question is not clear.  However, something of this sort should do what you want.

Comment: You can avoid double linking to a table member_label by using merge instead of update, which produces the same result.